# Silverstripe ModelAdmin drag and drop Sortable

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I wanted to make my ModelAdmin GridField to be sortable with drag and drop. I tried adding this code:

```
$gridFieldName = 'Destributors';
    $gridField = $form->Fields()->fieldByName($gridFieldName);

    if ($gridField) {
        $gridField->getConfig()->addComponent(new GridFieldFilterHeader(),new GridFieldSortableRows('SortOrder'));
    }
```

But it seems it is not working. Any idea on how can I implement it?

Any help will greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is code that I have used on an SS3 project. You should be able to easily update it to SS4.

```
<?php
class MealsModelAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

    private static $managed_models = array(
        'MealAttribute',
        'MenuCategory'
    );

    private static $url_segment = 'configuration';
    private static $menu_title = 'Configuration';

    public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null){
        $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);
        $model = singleton($this->modelClass);

        /** add sorting if we have a field for... */
        if (class_exists('GridFieldOrderableRows')
            && $model->hasField('SortOrder')
            && $gridField=$form->Fields()->dataFieldByName($this->sanitiseClassName($this->modelClass))) {
            if($gridField instanceof GridField) {
                $gridField->getConfig()->addComponent(new GridFieldOrderableRows('SortOrder'));
            }
        }

        return $form;
    }

}
```

Comment: Working like a charm, I just had to use the full name space in the class_exists condition : `if (class_exists('Symbiote\GridFieldExtensions\GridFieldOrderableRows') && ...` since `GridFieldOrderableRows` is available as a composer package for SS4

Comment: This worked well. I just used GridFieldSortableRows instead ( from the UndefinedOffset package )